# Is it known for which pairs of integers Ackermann 's function is commutative?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ackermann-function

I was recently writing test for checking the termination of programs and I wanted to write some difficult condition to verify so that the solver didn't use the if-condition to simplify the goal to proof.

It turned that writing in the if, `ackermann(x,y) == 1` (for the definition of Ackermann see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function))  was sufficient to confuse the solver, but I also tried `ackermann(x,y) == ackermann(y,x)` and of course the solver didn't go better on this instance.

I'm thinking of other programs that imply difficult problems in mathematics, for instance the so-called Collatz problem (also Syracuse, Kakutani, Hasse or Ulam's problem):

```
while n > 1 do
 if(n mod 2) != 0 then n = 3n + 1 
 else n = n div 2
```

So my question is, is there any problem with Ackermann's commutativity. Is it known what pairs (if any) of numbers make it commutative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from $m=n$ the only cases of commutativity are $A(1,0)=A(0,1)$ and $A(2,0)=A(0,2)$.  In all other cases $m \gt n \implies A(m,n) \gt A(n,m)$.  I don't have a nice proof of that, but the height of the tower is *much* more important than the numbers that make up the tower.  You can find cases where different pairs of arguments give equal values, like $A(0,12)=A(1,11)=A(2,5)=A(3,1)=A(4,0)=13$ and $A(0,65534)=A(1,65533)=A(2,32765)=A(3,13)=A(4,1)=65533$
Looking at the definition, given $A(m,n)$ you can also express it as $A(p,q)$ for every $p \lt m$.

Answer (score 3):

To finish up Ross Millikan's answer:

Note that if $m>n>1$ we have

\begin{align}A(m,n)&=A(m-1,A(m,n-1))\\&\ge A(n,A(m,n-1))\\&\ge A(n,m+n-1)\\&>A(n,m)\end{align}

using the fact that the Ackermann function is increasing in all arguments.

Comment: very helpful addition indeed!